# Coding a recursive function for highest possible input

Tags: math, arithmetic, fastest-code, recursion

***Challenge***

You are given the following function:- [image] which is the same as:-

[image]

with the base cases q(r, b, L) = 1 whenever r ≤ L, q(r, 0, L) = 0, if r > L and  q(r, 0, L) = 1, if r ≤ L.

Your task is to code a program that takes r as input, and outputs the value of q(r, r - L, L) for all L taking integer values from 1 to (r-1), where r is any nonnegative integer.

***Example 1***

***Input***

> Enter the value of r: 2

***Output***

> q(2,1,1) = 0.3333333333

***Example 2***

***Input***

> Enter the value of r: 3

***Output***

> q(3,2,1) = 0.1
>
> q(3,1,2) = 0.5

***Winning criterion***

The code that can correctly output q(r, r-L, L) for all L taking integer values from 1 to (r-1), for **the highest value of r**, in less than 300 seconds. In case of a tie, the code with lesser runtime will be considered. As this is a runtime-based challenge, I shall test all submissions on my machine.

Comment: Your sum/product notations both use the letter k as their variable. I think this is technically valid, but it might be easier to read if you used two different letters.

Comment: @stokastic: Edited, thanks.

Comment: Which of the two base cases takes priority when `r < L` and `b = 0`? And what value of `b` will be used in the winning criterion?

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Thanks for pointing this out. The first case (r ≤ L) takes priority. Edited accordingly. Also, the highest input value of b for which the code produces a correct output in less than 300 seconds, will be used.

Comment: @PeterTaylor let me guess: are you working on a closed-form?

Comment: That doesn't really answer my second question. The current statement of the winning criterion says that it's the highest value of r with tie-breaking on the highest value of b, but since the program always takes both values it doesn't make any sense to talk about the highest value of r unless you define a function from the input value of r in the non-tiebreak case to the value of b. In other words, you need to specify a sequence of (r, b) *pairs* for the winning criterion to make any sense.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you're trying to say. Why doesn't it make sense to talk about the highest value of r? To compare two submissions, first the highest values of r that can be evaluated by both the codes are looked at, *regardless of the value of b*. In the case of a tie-breaker, the highest value of b that can be evaluated by both codes, *for that tied value of r*, is looked at. Could you provide an example in terms of two submissions to show how this current winning criterion breaks down?

Comment: One way of looking at it is that the recursion is in b as well as r, so for every r there will be a different b for which a submission can meet the time constraint. If that function from r to b has different asymptotics for two submissions, they're incomparable. Another way is that if we take b = 0, the limit on how far a submission can go is I/O-bound; if we take b = 1000, it's CPU-bound.

Comment: Oh, I think I somewhat understand the problem now. I can't think of a way to get around it though. Do you have suggestions for an alternate winning criterion?

Comment: I presume you came across the function in some context which gives you more intuition for how it should behave than I have, but the easiest fix would be to say the highest value of `x` such that input `r=x, b=x` completes within the time constraint.

Comment: Yes, I do know the context behind the function, but sadly, it doesn't give me much insight into how the function behaves, other than the fact that the number of recursions increases quite rapidly with increasing values of r and b. It's one of the reasons I started this challenge; to see if others could come up with better, possibly less recursive approaches to understand this function.

Comment: That fix sounds good enough. Let's go with it.

Comment: @JobinIdiculla One problem with using `r = b` is that the values tend towards `1` very quickly: http://codepad.org/RT33DjpB

Comment: @primo: Thank you, working on a fix.

Comment: @primo: Could you run your code for r = 50, b = 22 please?

Comment: @JobinIdiculla slightly more interesting values: http://codepad.org/2IWYwqSj Although I think something like `b = r-L` might be better: http://codepad.org/5ZbrN1ai

Comment: @primo: Hmm, I see. Could you try the code for r = 50 and b = 25 as well, please? It's just that my code isn't efficient enough, for values beyond r = 24.

Comment: @JobinIdiculla Also including `r = 100; b = 50`: http://codepad.org/QWb9v2uz

Comment: @primo: Thank you! I think your idea of b = r - L works much better. I think it'll be better to go with that. :)

Comment: Though this would mean the challenge statement would change (r becomes the only input). Is it alright if I change the challenge statement, given that other coders might already be working on the original statement?

Comment: @JobinIdiculla I don't think it would be a problem, because it only affects the input, rather than the function definition. It does affect the winning criterion, but they're aren't any submissions yet anyway.

Comment: @primo: I see. It's done.

Comment: `q(r, r-1, 1) == 2(r!)^2/(2r)!` (http://oeis.org/A001700) and `r(r, 1, r-1) == (r-1)/(r+1)` (trivial). Haven't checked the others yet.

Comment: In the interests of clarity, `q(r,r-1,1)` is the *reciprocal* of A001700.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Java

I've applied some algebraic transformation and dynamic programming.

```java
public class CodeGolf42234 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int r = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        for (int L = 1; L < r; L++) System.out.println(qDouble5(r, r-L, L));
    }

    private static double qDouble5(int _r, int _b, int L) {
        double[][] q = new double[_r+1][_b+1];
        for (int r = 0; r <= L; r++) {
            for (int b = 0; b < q[r].length; b++) q[r][b] = 1;
        }
        for (int r = L + 1; r < q.length; r++) {
            for (int b = 1 + (r - L - 1)/L; b < q[r].length; b++) {
                double sum = 0, m = 1;
                for (int k = 0; k <= L; k++) {
                    sum += m * q[r-k][b-1];
                    m = m * (r - k) / (r + b - 1 - k);
                }
                q[r][b] = sum * b / (r + b);
            }
        }
        return q[_r][_b];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the submission. On my system (Windows, Netbeans IDE), the highest value of r that can be evaluated using this code, in under 300 seconds (297 seconds) is 731. Good job, Peter! :)

Answer (score 1):

### Java

Here's a recursive solution. Just like you wanted. You can always uncomment the output and display it if you want.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class HeaderFinder
{
static ArrayList<Double> answers = new ArrayList<Double>();
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int r = scanner.nextInt();
    for(int b=r-1; b!=0; b--)
        for(int L=r-1; L!=0; L--)
            answers.add(formulate(r,b,L));

//  int i=-1;
//      for(int b=r-1; b!=0; b--)
//          for(int L=r-1; L!=0; L--)
//              System.out.println("q("+r+", "+b+", "+L+") = "+answers.get(++i));

}

public static double formulate(double r, double b, double L)
{
    if(b==0)
        if(r>L)
            return 0.0;
        else
            return 1;
    if(r<=L)
        return 1;
    double partone = (b/(r+b));
    double result = 0.0;
    for(int k=1; k<=L; k++)
    {
        result+=summation(r, b, k) * (b/(r+b-k)) * formulate(r-k, b-1, L);
    }
    return (partone * formulate(r, b-1, L)) + result;
}

public static double summation(double r, double b, int k)
{
    double rb = r+b;
    double mul=r/rb;
    for(int i=1; i<k; i++)
    {
        mul*=(r-i)/(rb-i);
    }
    return mul;
}
}
```